# How to Pass Neo4j 2.0 Server Plugin Parameters

Tags: neo4j

I made a really simple Neo4j 2.0 Server Plugin that works great without any parameters.  However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pass a string parameter to the plugin.  I have one optional parameter called "criteria".  This should be very simple.  I'm just not very familiar with CURL, java, or REST.

```
@Name( "getLabelsForSearch" )
@Description( "Get all labels that match the search criteria from the Neo4j graph database" )
@PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
public Iterable<String> getLabelsForSearch( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb, @Description("The search criteria string") @Parameter (name = "criteria", optional = true) String criteria )
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
     labels.add(criteria);

     try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
     {
       for ( Label label : GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllLabels() )
        {
           labels.add(criteria);
           //This is just for testing
           labels.add(label.name());
        }

       tx.success();
     }
    return labels;
}
```

I tried a few different ways with curl:

```
curl -X POST http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch?criteria=thisorthat

curl -X POST http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch/criteria/thisorthat

curl -X POST http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch -data { "criteria" : "thisorthat"}
```

I've been following this page and it has an example of passing a parameter.  Maybe I'm just overlooking something?
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-plugins.html

This is the json information I get back when I do a GET request on the url:

```
http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch/ 

{
"extends" : "graphdb",
"description" : "Get all labels that match the search criteria from the Neo4j graph   database",
"name" : "getLabelsForSearch",
"parameters" : [ {
  "description" : "The search criteria string",
  "optional" : true,
  "name" : "criteria",
  "type" : "string"
   } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the parameters in JSON format. Therefore it's crucial to specify the content type and to put the payload in quotes, so try

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -data '{ "criteria" : "thisorthat"}' http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch
```

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!  However, I didn't get your curl to work.  I did get this to work: curl  –H “Accept: application/json” –X POST –d “criteria=type” http://icexad01:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/getLabelsForSearch